How do I run sqlite INSERT INTO queries from a txt file in Flutter?
I have a txt file with sql INSERT INTO queries and values. I'd like to run them all at once in Dart/Flutter with the sqlite plugin. Is this possible?
INSERT INTO article (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Banana') ;
INSERT INTO article (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Orange') ;
INSERT INTO article (id, name) VALUES (3, 'Apple') ;

All methods I'm trying don't work

you should extract those values (1,'banana') , (2 , 'orange') from that file and store them temporarily within a list, then construct single insert query for all of these values. got it!

Thank you very much. Is it possible to help us with an example?

ok, look at my answer.

tl;dr
Here's an example demonstrating a file containing a many insert queries like you mentioned in the question actually it contains the same insert queries:
Here's what i have put in the file(inserts.txt), exactly in a single line:

INSERT INTO article (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Banana') ; INSERT INTO
article (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Orange') ; INSERT INTO article (id,
name) VALUES (3, 'Apple') ;

Here's how the file is read:
The result of that function is just a single string representing the content of the file or null if the file is not exist:
Future<String?> getInsertQuery({required String fileName}) async {
  File file = File(fileName);
  if (await file.exists()) {
    RandomAccessFile accessFile = await file.open();
    var list = utf8.decode(await accessFile.read(file.lengthSync()));
    return list;
  }

after reading that file, you need to extract the values from all of these instructions:
List<String> getValues({required String allQueries}) {
  bool foundValue = false;
  String currentValue = "";
  List<String> valuesList = [];

  for (int i = 1; i < allQueries.length - 1; i++) {
    if (allQueries.codeUnitAt(i).compareTo('('.codeUnitAt(0)) == 0 &&
            allQueries.codeUnitAt(i + 1).compareTo('i'.codeUnitAt(0)) != 0 ||
        i == allQueries.length - 2) {
      foundValue = true;
      if (currentValue.isNotEmpty) {
        valuesList.add(currentValue);
      }
      currentValue = "";
    }
    if (allQueries.codeUnitAt(i - 1).compareTo(')'.codeUnitAt(0)) == 0) {
      foundValue = false;
    }
    if (foundValue) {
      currentValue += allQueries.substring(i, i + 1);
    }
  }
  return valuesList;
}
  return null;
}

The above function just return a list containing all of the values ex:
[(1, 'Banana') ,(2, 'Orange') ,(3, 'Apple')]
The hardest part has been done, now construct your insert query:
void writeQuery({required List<String> values}) {
  String query = 'INSERT INTO article (id, name) VALUES ';
  for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    query += '${values[i]} ${i == values.length - 1 ? ';' : ','}';
  }
  print(query);
}

It takes the list of values and returns the query in string representation:
output:
 INSERT INTO article (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Banana') ,(2, 'Orange') ,(3, 'Apple') ;

and of course, here's the main function:
void main() async {
  final String? queries = await getInsertQuery(
      fileName:
          'give it the file path');

  if (queries == null) {
    print('No Data found or file not exist');
  } else {
    writeQuery(values: getValues(allQueries: queries));
  }
}

after all you need to get the accumulative query and pass it to your database Manager to insert them:
  INSERT INTO article (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Banana') ,(2, 'Orange') ,(3, 'Apple') ;

for more info, see that code in my repo
